# Print only letters from a string

Tags: c, string, io, character, ascii

I must create a program that takes in a string and only prints out the letters (the uppercase and lowercase). I really need some help in working this program out.

for example:

Input: Cat808her_+in_+e87

output: Catherine

Input: 2012 Nov 06_ENEE140$$$exa !m

output: NovENEEexam

```
#include <stdio.h>

char string[256];
int character;
int c=0;

int main(){
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    while((character=getchar()) != '\n'){
        if((character>='A'&&character<='Z')||(character>='a'&&character<='z')){
            c++;
            string[c]=character;
        }
        printf("Only letters: %s\n", string);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it does not work at all, nothing prints out.

Comment: do `c++` after assign.

Comment: You only want to handle ASCII?

Comment: i only need to print out upper and lower case letters

Comment: @user3473994: I asked because outside ASCII with single-byte charsets, you must use isalpha(), with multibyte character sets like UTF-8 you need other libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your loop, you are first incrementing your `c`, then assigning the letter obtained inside `string[c]`, provided that the conditions in `if` are fulfilled.

This means that it will start off the assignment from `string[1]`, leaving the first one to remain as it initially was. As a file-scope array, `char string[256]` has its characters initialized to zero. Thus, your first element will remain as zero.

A zero encounter means end-of-string for `"%s"` type-specifier inside `printf` as well as for many other things. For this reason, nothing will get printed, because the string starting off with `'\0'` technically doesn't have anything.

Just place `c++` after the assignment, and your code should be alright. Optionally you could use the following:

```
...
    string[c++] = character;
...
```

You don't have to include a terminating zero, since your string already is initialized with zeroes.

You could add some check to not let `c` get beyond 255, even 254, so you won't accidentally assign something to the very last zero, or try to access anything beyond that, which you are not allowed to access.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
    {
    char string[255+1];
    char *cp;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
    printf("Only letters: ");
    for(cp=string; *cp; ++cp)
        if(isalpha(*cp))
           printf("%c", *cp);

    printf("\n");
    return(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the "string[c++] = character;" correction, for the line:

```
if((character>='A'&&character<='Z')||(character>='a'&&character<='z')){
```

You could or should use the isalpha() function (after #include <ctype.h> at the top) like this:

```
if(isalpha(character){
```

For the default "C" locale this is exactly what you want.  You probably also want to use fgets() instead of getchar(), which will let you prevent overruns of your input buffer.  And initialize your strings to all nulls with:

```
char string[256]={0};
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing character values like `c > 'A'` will not work correctly in some locales where the collating sequence differs from the C locale; using isalnum(c) is the way to go.

Comment: He's not looking for alpha-numeric, just alpha. So it would be `isalpha()`, as @mahonri-moriancumer said.

Comment: Agreed.  However, was making a point about not doing the character comparison explicitly.  Reasonable compilers will inline the isalpha() or isalnum() calls so it is usually more economical to do this the right way.

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char string[256];
int character;
int c=0;

int main(){
 printf("Enter a string: ");
 while((character=getchar()) != '\n'){
     if((character>='A'&&character<='Z')||(character>='a'&&character<='z')){

         string[c++]=character;
     }

 }
 printf("Only letters: %s\n", string);
 return 0;
}
```